# error: incomplete type is not allowed with when i tried to implement nested structure

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I tried to create a structure and like the following and it will be more like nested structure, I had created but its throwing an error like the incomplete type is not allowed while calling the structure `SGenObjData` from struct `SGebObjLst`

```
struct SGenObjLst
{
    unsigned short                  objectIdx[OBJ_MAX_ID + 1][SRC_LIST_NMBR]; /* #RTAS: input               */
    struct SGenObjData              objects[OBJ_MAX_NMBR];      /* #RTAS: input               */
    unsigned short                  objNmbr;      /* #RTAS: input               */
    unsigned char                   modifiedFlag;      /* #RTAS: input               */
    unsigned char                   validFlag;      /* #RTAS: input               */
};



struct SGenObjData
{
    enum TObjType                     recogType; /* #RTAS: input               */ /* Object type (vehicle, pedestrian, ...)                                      */
    enum TObjType                     commuType; /* #RTAS: input               */ /* Object type (vehicle, pedestrian, ...)                                      */
    enum TSource                      source; /* #RTAS: input               */ /* id offset e.g. 0 for "GenericEnvObjectList" = "GEOL"                        */
    unsigned short                  id; /* #RTAS: input               */ /* object id                                                                   */
    unsigned char                   reliability; /* #RTAS: input               */ /* 0: undefined 1: very low  2: low 3: medium 4: high 5: very high             */
    unsigned char                   vulnerability; /* #RTAS: input               */ /* 0: not vulnerable (e.g. parked car), ... 5: very vulnerable (e.g. child)    */
    unsigned char                   dangerousness; /* #RTAS: input               */ /* 0: not dangerous for ego vehicle (e.g. a small bush), ... 5: very dangerous (e.g. wall)     */
    TTime                           timestamp; /* #RTAS: input, unit: us     */ /* timestamp [us]                                                              */
    TTime                           measTimestamp; /* #RTAS: input, unit: us     */ /* original measured timestamp (w/o correction due to delay time compensation) */
    float                           x; /* #RTAS: input, unit: m      */ /* x position (ego vehicle front is zero)[m]                                   */
    float                           err_x; /* #RTAS: input, unit: m      */ /* x position error [m]                                                        */
    float                           y; /* #RTAS: input, unit: m      */ /* y position (ego vehicle middle axle is zero) [m]                            */
    float                           err_y; /* #RTAS: input, unit: m      */ /* y position error [m]                                                        */
    float                           vx_rel; /* #RTAS: input, unit: m/s    */ /* relative velocity x [m/s]                                                   */
    float                           vy_rel; /* #RTAS: input, unit: m/s    */ /* relative velocity y [m/s]                                                   */
    float                           ax_rel; /* #RTAS: input, unit: m/s**2 */ /* relative acceleration x [m/s2]                                              */
    float                           vx_abs; /* #RTAS: input, unit: m/s    */ /* absolute velocity x [m/s]                                                   */
    float                           vy_abs; /* #RTAS: input, unit: m/s    */ /* absolute velocity y [m/s]                                                   */
    float                           ax_abs; /* #RTAS: input, unit: m/s**2 */ /* absolute acceleration x [m/s2]                                              */
    float                           width; /* #RTAS: input, unit: m      */ /* width of object                                                             */
    float                           err_width; /* #RTAS: input, unit: m      */ /* width error of object                                                       */
    float                           length; /* #RTAS: input, unit: m      */ /* length of object                                                            */
    float                           err_length; /* #RTAS: input, unit: m      */ /* length error of object                                                      */
    float                           height; /* #RTAS: input, unit: m      */ /* height of object                                                            */
    float                           err_height; /* #RTAS: input, unit: m      */ /* height error of object                                                      */
    float                           maxVel; /* #RTAS: input, unit: m/s    */ /* maximal speed observed during tracking                                      */

    unsigned char                   vldty_width; /* #RTAS: input               */
    unsigned char                   vldty_err_width; /* #RTAS: input               */
    unsigned char                   vldty_length; /* #RTAS: input               */
    unsigned char                   vldty_err_length; /* #RTAS: input               */
    unsigned char                   vldty_height; /* #RTAS: input               */
    unsigned char                   vldty_err_height; /* #RTAS: input               */
    unsigned char                   vldty_x; /* #RTAS: input               */
    unsigned char                   vldty_err_x; /* #RTAS: input               */
    unsigned char                   vldty_y; /* #RTAS: input               */
    unsigned char                   vldty_err_y; /* #RTAS: input               */
    unsigned char                   vldty_vx_rel; /* #RTAS: input               */
    unsigned char                   vldty_vy_rel; /* #RTAS: input               */
    unsigned char                   vldty_ax_rel; /* #RTAS: input               */
    unsigned char                   vldty_vx_abs; /* #RTAS: input               */
    unsigned char                   vldty_vy_abs; /* #RTAS: input               */
    unsigned char                   vldty_ax_abs; /* #RTAS: input               */
    unsigned char                   vldty_maxVel; /* #RTAS: input               */
};

// CREATE STRUCT 
struct SGenObjLst          objectList;
struct SGenObjData         objectData;

struct SGenDataLst                  //sundar
{
    struct SGenObjLst          objectList;
    struct SGenObjData         objectData;
};

struct SGenDataLst SGenDataLst;
```

Comment: PLEASE format your question (edit and indent the code), its burning my eyes

Comment: You don't see anything wrong with your formatting, do you?

Comment: Change the order of structs' definitions.

Comment: Types need be declared before use, so you can't use a `SGenObjData` before you tell the compiler what it is. Also, you don't need the extra `struct` when declaring variables of a struct.

Answer (score 0):

You called the object in the same name as the type. You cannot do that, because then the compiler interprets the type as another decleration, for example :

```
struct SGenDataLst SGenDataLst; // is the equivallent of:
int int;
```

Would not work - The compiler will see both the `int`s and try to delcare a first int, which will be empty - because there's no name between both the ints, and then another new one. Thus you might get many different errors, while the only problem is the duplicate name.

Try this:

```
struct SGenDataLst myDataList; // or any other name.
```

**EDIT**:

From the comments I noticed you also declared your structs in the wrong order. This will also raise a similar error to the one you got, because most C compilers read upsite down. Change the order, as amartel suggested, and your program should work fine.

Comment: but the error is not in SGenDataLst, it is in...
       struct SGenObjData              objects[OBJ_MAX_NMBR];

Comment: @MeenakshySundaresan There are 2 errors I've mentioned - the structs order, and the naming. Change these, and your program should work fine.